# Why am I not getting an error?

Tags: c++

In the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int i = 99;

for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
cout << endl << endl;

cout << i << endl;

return 0;
}
```

I am not getting an error on compilation.
My question is why this is happening.
The `int` variable `i` was declared twice. The first time `i` was declared in the `main()` function and thus its scope will be this whole `main()` function including the `for` loop. The second time `i` was declared with the `for` loop and thus its scope will be only the `for` loop. So, now inside the scope of the `for` loop there exists two int variables`i`. Shouldn't this be a cause of error? And if not why?

Second thing is the output I am getting:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   6
>   7
>   8
>   9
>   10
>   
>   99

I also don't understand the output. Why after the execution of the `for` loop, the value of `i` that is being printed is 99 and not 10.

Comment: You can declare variables with the same name in distinct scopes. `for()` starts a new scope.

Comment: So would a variable declared outside the for() not be usable inside it? But we can. For example: `int j = 0; for(into i = 1; i < 5; i++){j++;}` would be perfectly valid but is it differentiating between the two i variables in my program?

Comment: Sure you can do that. Just omit the declaration in the first part of the `for()` loop like: `for(i = 1;`.

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define variables with the same names in different scopes.  The first variable `i` is defined in the scope of the `main` function. In the loop there is another implied nested and anonymous scope for the variables you declare for the loop.

For the compiler, the code

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

is more or less equivalent to

```
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't this still lie in the scope of the main() function? For example when we declare a variables outside of the main() function its scope is the whole program. So wouldn't declaring a variable inside the main() make its scope the whole of the main() function and thus wouldn't the two variable clash?

Comment: @Natsu DEfining a variable in a nested scope *hides* the previous variable declaration. In the nested scope, the previous variable will be unavailable. You can even define the nested scopes variable to be of a completely different type. Any [beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) would have told you this.